# CanResize окно с тенью

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужен стиль для окна имеющего тень в 4 направлениях (left, top, right, bottom), размер которого можно было бы менять мышью.

Набросок стиля:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome NonClientFrameEdges="None" GlassFrameThickness="-1" CornerRadius="0" ResizeBorderThickness="5" CaptionHeight="30"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Margin="20" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">

                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect Direction="-90" BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Black"/>
                            </Border.Effect>

                            <Grid Background="White">
                                <AdornerDecorator>
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </AdornerDecorator>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Проблема стиля:

1. ResizeBorderThickness определяет Thickness для бордера, которого в принципе нет - он описывается чисто логически и является просто видимым (не Transporent) краем окна указанной ширины.
2. Для хрома окна нет такого понятия как отступ. Он всегда сверху. Даже если там верхняя тень...

Единственное *решение* которое я вижу - нарисовать тень на более низком уровне. Как?

Да и поясните же за что отвечает WindowChrome.GlassFrameThickness? Что будет если ему отрицательное значение присвоить?

Comment: Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome.glassframethickness(v=vs.110).aspx), если установить отрицательные значения, то «стеклянная» подложка будет распространяться на _всё_ окно. Если положительные, подложка будет только данной толщины. // Вот ещё по теме: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome/

Comment: А если, например, вот такое значение: -1,10,10,10? Я так полагаю, это равносильно -1,-1,-1,-1. Статью по ссылке я читал. Пример там не загрузить, т.к. ссылка ломаная.

Comment: Угу. Насколько я понял, одно отрицательное значение превращает всё в -1.

Comment: А что с ResizeBorderThickness? Я так думаю, тут ничего не поделать... Только написать свой Transporent бордюр на нужном расстоянии от края окна и наделить его функциональностью ресайза. А вот с тенью не знаю. Делать свой хром что ли?

Comment: Ну как свой. Его подобие в виде простого Border.